# P-Values decrease when additional significant variables added (multicollinearity?)

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value, multicollinearity, small-sample

I am doing a study for my masters correlating two separate development indicators to election results for the incumbent government.  Unfortunately, I was only only able to get 11 years worth of data for these indicators, due to financial restrictions and what is publicly available from the government.

-Running a simple linear regression with the first indicator as the independent variable and election results as the dependent, Indicator 1 was significant with a P value of .02

-Doing the same with Indicator 2, it was also significant, with a P value of .04

-However, when I run a multiple regression with both variables, neither is even close to significant, with P values both above .5

I turned to the internet for help, and came up with two theories:
1) I need a larger sample size to properly run a multiple regression
2) Multicollinearity (something I was not familiar with) is the issue

I did a regression with indicator 1 as the independent and 2 as the dependent, and discovered they are highly correlated with each other. This leads me to believe multicollinearity is my problem.

1) am i right, is it multicollinearity?

2) if so, what (if anything) can I do about it?

3) If not, then what else could be the problem?

I studied regression this year for my masters, but had little statistical knowledge beforehand, so this is somewhat new to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Yes, you are correct: the two indicators are competing to tell you the same information, which is called multicollinearity (it's more technical than that, of course)
2) Use only one of the predictors: if they're essentially giving the same information (high correlation, resulting in multicollinearity) then one predictor speaks for both of them. 
3) More data is always better. 
4) What are the dependent and independent variables? It sounds as if the dependent is categorical which changes the regression. 
5) It's helpful to know what hypothesis is being tested that results in those p-values.

Comment: The dependent variable is the percentage of the vote received by the incumbent party The independent variables are the approval rating of the Prime Minister, and the change in real personal income 

So, is the conclusion I should draw that personal income changes strongly effect the prime ministers approval rating, which then correlates with the percentage of the vote his party receives?

Comment: I foresee issues with the approval rating variable. How is that measured? Is it a "1=very dissatisfied to 5=very satisfied" measurement or a continuous variable? What I'm getting at is that if all of your variables (independents and dependent) are continuous then you're in the clear with regression as you've been doing it. If not, other techniques are required. To answer your questions, correlation basically means "hand in hand". So, increases in the approval *tend to be* observed with increased personal income change and decreases in approval *tend* with decreases in personal income change.

Comment: No, its the percentage that approve of him. The question is "How do you feel about the performance of PM______ - Approve or Disapprove"

Comment: I'm going to move into the answers box so that I can get some LaTeX going and hopefully answer how to fix the multicollinearity.

Comment: Quick question: do you have the actual incomes or just the changes? That is a big difference.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that regression is new to you so I'm going to include some detail.

---

So you've got $[ y_1, y_2, ..., y_{11} ]$, which represent the percentage of the vote in year $1, 2, ..., 11$ received by the incumbent party as the dependent variable. Your working hypothesis is that this dependent variable depends on $P$, personal income change, and $A$, approval, of which you have eleven measurements each. When doing linear regression, the working hypothesis is that $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1P + \beta_2A + \epsilon_i \iff Y_i = X\beta + \epsilon_i$$  in which $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and the second formula is equivalent to the first, just in matrix notation (i.e. $X$ has first column of ones, second column $A$ and third column $P$ and $\beta$ is the vector $\beta = [\beta_0 \beta_1 \beta_2$]). Let's talk about this model assumption: do you have any evidence or hunch even to think that an increase in $P$ and an increase $A$ will result in an increase in $Y$? If you don't, then regression is returning a line of best fit which isn't all that informative. If you do believe these quantities to be linearly related or are testing the hypothesis (i.e. $A$ increases and $P$ increases $\implies$ $Y$ increases) then you're after the $\beta$'s which will tell you what combination of $A$ and $P$ make $Y$ increase (how much to weight each variable, basically).

You think that the predictors are correlated, which is possible. [Here](http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-compute-pearsons-correlation-coefficients/) is an easy walkthrough of how to calculate $r_{PA}$, the correlation between variables $P$ and $A$. If it turns out that they are correlated, then the $X$ matrix above can't easily be inverted due to multicollinearity, which is a lack of independence of the columns of $X$. Mathematically, the estimate for $\beta$ is  $$\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}Y$$
So if you have multicollinearity, it means that $(X^{T}X)$ is close to not being invertible (which happens when the columns of $X$ are not independent), meaning that your estimate for the weights, $\beta$, won't exist. That's bad. There are methods for ameliorating this using variance inflating factors, but given that you only have 11 data, the best solution is simply to choose which predictor about whose relationship to $Y$ you want to make claims. Then, run regression with just the one predictor so your model looks like 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{predictor} + \epsilon_i$$ (in which $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $predictor = A$ or $P$). Now, the $p$-value that is displayed is the probability that that $\beta_1 = 0$ i.e. that the chosen variable has no effect on $Y$. Loosely put, a $p$-value of 0.05 indicates that the probability, given these 11 data, that $\beta_1 = 0$ is 0.05.

Comment: I support this answer. As a side note on "what can I do about it?", I would propose to scale "change in real personal income" appropriately, perform PCA, then make regression on the first principal component. See if $\beta$ will be lower and $R^2$ higher.  This is beyond the beginner level though.

Comment: Yes, I understood some of what scouserInTrouser's said, but some of it went over my head.

Comment: Why do I need to calculate this rPA, if I ran a regression with P as the independent and A as the dependent already, and found that they are highly correlated that way?

Is there a quick and easily-understandable way to fix it so that P and A are significant in the multiple regression model?

or

Is there some useful conclusion for my paper that I can derive from the fact that their is multicollinearity?

Comment: ie. If i already believed going into this that PM approval was the most important factor in determining wether voters would support the incumbent  government, then  would this result support the theory that changes in personal income effect voters evaluations of the PM, which is then highly linked to their decision of wether to support the incumbant government?

so, their is a "chain of causality" going: P -> A -> Y

As opposed to my initial hypothesis, where P and A -> Y separately?

Comment: @PaulKenney Please do not use the word causality anywhere near this analysis. Correlation DOES NOT IMPLY causation, especially in this discipline and with as few data as you have. If you end up with a positive value of $\beta_P$ then, yes, you may conclude that *based on these 11 data*, an increase in personal income is correlated with an increase in voters' evaluations of the Prime Minister. Then stop there; don't try to "chain" the predictors' effects to the cause because (a) you have too few data and (b) the two effects are correlated themselves.

Comment: Yes, I understand that correlation does not imply causation, but if voters formed there opinions this way, wouldn't that be supported by that fact that A and P were too correlated to one and other to develop a model to predict Y?

A similar study was done in the US using only 12 midterm elections (as that was all the data they had in 1975) and a multiple regression of A and P explained 70% of the variance in Y (it was updated in 2005 with similar results).

Comment: Could I not then theorize that the fact A and P were too highly correlated in Canada for this model to work effectively, suggests that people in my country choose which member to vote for based heavily on opinion of the PM, and that they judge the PM based on changes in the economy. As opposed to the US, where member of congress are more independent, and economic conditions and Presidential evaluation are more distinct considerations (although, the economy obviously influences presidential opinions too)

Comment: @ScouserInTrousers I used SPSS to check the VIF to see if their was multicollinearity, and it appears there is not...the VIF was 1.725. Now I am really confused

Comment: @lanenok?
_____

Comment: I completely support the answer and comments of  ScouserInTrousers, in particular the comment with ´don't try to "chain" the predictors' effects to the cause' ´ (upvoted). There is hardly anything more to say.